# Оптимизация кода (алгоритм Крускала)

Tags: java, алгоритм, оптимизация, графы

Задание - реализация алгоритма Крускала для вычисления минимальной суммарной длины дорожек в парке аттракционов. 
Лимит времени - 5 секунд.

При тесте на 3900 аттракционов, программа занимает больше 5 секунд, дело все, как я понял, в реализации нахождения длины дорожки (обычный алгоритм нахождения расстояния от точки до точки). Если это так, то как оптимизировать программу? Других способов, вроде как, нет. Если же это не так, то из-за чего?

Ввод - количество аттракционов и их координаты.
Вывод - минимальная суммарная длина дорог между ними.

Пример:

- 5
- 26 71
- 15 89
- 62 63
- 78 19
- 96 23

Вывод:

**- 123.23**

```
import java.util.*;

class Node {
    int x, y, z = 0;
    Node parent = this;
}

class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
    int first, second;
    double length;

    public int compareTo(Edge arr) {
        if (this.length > arr.length) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.length == arr.length) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

public class Kruskal {
    public static double MST(ArrayList<Node> arr, ArrayList<Edge> edges) {
        Collections.sort(edges);
        int i = 0;
        double result = 0;
        while (i <  edges.size()) {
            int x = edges.get(i).first;
            int y = edges.get(i).second;
            Node rX = find(arr.get(x));
            Node rY = find(arr.get(y));
            if (rX != rY) {
                result += edges.get(i).length;
                if (rX.z < rY.z) {
                    rX.parent = rY;
                } else {
                    rY.parent = rX;
                    if (rY.z == rX.z && rX != rY) {
                        rX.z++;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Node find(Node x) {
        if (x.parent == x) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return x.parent = find(x.parent);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int i, j, count = 0;



        ArrayList<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result.add(new Node());
            result.get(i).x = in.nextInt();
            result.get(i).y = in.nextInt();
        }

        ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                edges.add(new Edge());
                edges.get(count).first = i;
                edges.get(count).second = j;
                edges.get(count).length = Math.sqrt((result.get(j).x-result.get(i).x)*(result.get(j).x-result.get(i).x)+(result.get(j).y-result.get(i).y)*(result.get(j).y-result.get(i).y));
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%.2f", MST(result, edges));

    }
}
```

Comment: А что именно тормозит? Количество операций Крускала в данном случае пропорционально числу ребер ~ 10^7. Более 5 секунд кажется многовато.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в этой части программы:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        edges.add(new Edge());
        edges.get(count).first = i;
        edges.get(count).second = j;
        edges.get(count).length = Math.sqrt((result.get(j).x-result.get(i).x)*(result.get(j).x-result.get(i).x)+(result.get(j).y-result.get(i).y)*(result.get(j).y-result.get(i).y));
        count++;
    }
}
```

Создается ни много ни мало, а 7 603 050 ребер для 3900 узлов. Вы строите полносвязную топологию.

Задача найти алгоритм как отбросить заранее неудачные ребра. Без указания изначальных ребер на графе это получается задача о поиске оптимального пути, как я понимаю

Comment: Именно, задача сводится к тому, чтобы отбросить неудачные ребра заранее.

Comment: Ну значит так и сделать. Из полносвязного графа сделать что-то более оптимальное. Вместо добавления абсолютно всех ребер, оставлять только ребра для 5(к примеру) ближайших точек, для каждой из них. Это уже будет граф ближайших соседей. Но это все как-то не вписывается в рамки поставленной задачи

Answer (score 0):

Минимальная по длине сеть дорожек - евклидово минимальное остовное дерево ([ЕМОД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)). ЕМОД является подграфом [триангуляции Делоне](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5).

Решается задача так: строится триангуляция Делоне, из неё алгоритмом Крускала извлекается ЕМОД. Время работы - `NlogN`. Реализация сложная для обеих частей, если делать их действительно быстрыми.